# Allow console application to access Windows Authenticated web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC web application which uses Windows Authentication. So we do things like `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Now there is a console app I'm writing that would be run as part of a batch job. All this console app needs to do is call an `ActionResult` in the main web app which would then carry out some maintenance tasks.

Now, since the console app doesn't have an identity within the domain controller/Active Directory, the call using `System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString()` keeps throwing a 401 error.

My question is, is there a way to allow this application to call this link in the main web app without having to disable WindowsAuthentication in the web.config/IIS?

Any ideas/suggestions welcome.

All the console app contains is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["http://foo.com/"]);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: You're running this as a batch job, does that mean a Scheduled Task?  If so, what credentials are you using to run it.  Is it a domain account that should have access to your MVC account?

Comment: Yes, it is run as a Scheduled Task on the Server. It doesn't really matter what account it uses. All it needs is to be able to call that url.

Comment: If the web page you are trying to access uses Windows Authentication, then it absolutely matters what credentials your console app is running under.

Comment: Also, please post a more complete code example of how your app is creating and executing the HTTP request.

Comment: @MikeC Added the client code. It only has 1 line of code. That's all it needs really.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use UseDefaultCredentials:

```
        var client = new WebClient
                     {
                         UseDefaultCredentials = true
                     };
        client.DownloadString(address);
```

this will use whatever the console app is running as (which can be specified on the Scheduled Task settings).

Comment: As an advisory: this is unlikely to work when used in a windows service.